# R Shiny Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Z' not found

Tags: r, shiny

I'm creating a Shiny App that takes in a specific type of csv file from the user and ggplots it in a certain way. I'm using reactive values that will update the inputs every time the actionbutton is clicked. However, I've continuously been getting the error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Z' not found

Can you help me realize why? I've included a reproducible example for `Z` in the comments.

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(DT)

############################################################
# DEFINE REACTIVE VALUES
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
    ntext <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    #f1 = input$file1

    #inFile <- f1

    #if (is.null(inFile))
          return(NULL)

    #Z <- read.csv(inFile$datapath,sep=",")
    #   Name Track Position
    # 1    A     0        1
    # 2    G     0        1
    # 3    C     0        1
    # 4    T     0        1
    # 5    T     0        1
    # 6    T     0        1
    # 7   AG     1        1
    # 8   AG     1        2
    # 9   GC     1        2
    # 10  GC     1        3
    # 11  CT     1        3
    Z <- data.frame("Name"=c("A","G","C","T","T","T","AG","AG","GC","GC","CT","CT","AT","AT","CT","CT"),"Track"=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),"Position"=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,9,10,12,13))

    x <- length(levels(Z$Name))
    x.colors <- hcl(h=seq(15,375,length=(x+1)),l=65,c=100)[1:x]
    x.colors[1:4] <- c("blue","red","green","yellow")
    ########################################################
    # RETURN REACTIVE VALUES
    list(
          Z = Z,
          x.colors = x.colors,
         )
  })
  output$nText <- renderText({
    ntext()
  })
############################################################

############################################################  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    Z = ntext()$Z
    x.colors = ntext()$x.colors
    my_fill <- x.colors
    ggplot(NULL) +
      aes(x = Z$Track,
          y = Z$Position,
          fill = Z$Name,
          label = Z$Name) +
      geom_raster() +
      scale_fill_manual(values=my_fill) + 
      theme(legend.position="none",axis.title.y = element_blank(),axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
  })
############################################################
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("BlahBlah"), 
  fluidRow(
    column(3, wellPanel(
            h4("Upload the correct files"),
            fileInput('file1', 'Choose file',
                      accept=c('text/csv', 'text/plain','.csv')), 
            actionButton("goButton", "Update Plots")
          )
    )
  ),
  hr(), 
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           plotOutput("plot1", height = 1000,
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot2_brush",
                        resetOnNew = TRUE)
           )
    )
  )
))
```

Comment: add `if (!is.null(inFile))` and include all code with Z into it

Comment: `my_fill` object not defined

Comment: Thanks its working now